# MVC can't reach inside a tempdata condition

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc, tempdata

I'm trying to show user a notification with TempData but my code can't reach the script part. Any idea how can I fix this ? In debug I can see that TempData is not null.

```
<body>
 @if (TempData["error"] != null)
    {
        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="modal3"
         data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        @TempData["error"]
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button button4">Sign</button>
                        <button type="button" id="btnHideModal" class="btn btn-primary button button4">
                            Hide
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    @if (TempData["error"] != null)
    {
//This is the problem. In temporary breakpoint , it skips this part.
        @section Scripts{

        <script type="text/javascript">        
            const modal = document.getElementById("modal3")
            $(window).on('load', function () {
            modal.style.display = "block";
            });
            function closeModal() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>

        }
    }
</body>
```

Comment: I suspect that the value of `TempData["error"]` is removed once accessed it which is the default behavior. Did you try to move the `@section Scripts` part to the first `if` statement as same as second `if` statement. Or you need to keep the `TempData` with `TempData["error"].Keep()`.  [Reading](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc)

Comment: Hello, was the issue resolved? Have you tired the solution provided? Please let me know if any further assistance required on this.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Hi , thank you so much for your help. I had to change the structure completely because it wasn't helping my needs

Comment: However, based on your question, I have provided the correct solution, acceptance the answer it completely upto you. The solution was given based on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to show user a notification with TempData but my code can't
> reach the script part. Any idea how can I fix this ?

I have checked your shared `code snippet` and investigated that which seems alright and working as expected. I have set the `console` and `alert` both executed as expected. Finally, I tried to bind the `'@TempData["error"]'` within the modal and got the expected output as you can see below:

**Output:**
[image]

**HTML:**

I just kept your code as it is. Therefore, just you can replace your code.

**Script:**

```
<body>
    @if (TempData["error"] != null)
    {
        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="modal3"
         data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        @TempData["error"]
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button button4">Sign</button>
                        <button type="button" id="btnHideModal" class="btn btn-primary button button4">
                            Hide
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    @if (TempData["error"] != null)
    {
        //This is the problem. In temporary breakpoint , it skips this part.
       
        @section Scripts{

        <script type="text/javascript">
         
            const modal = document.getElementById("modal3")
            $(window).on('load', function () {
                console.log(modal);
                alert("Debug");
                modal.style.display = "block";
                $("#modal3").find(".modal-header").html('@TempData["error"]');
                $("#modal3").find(".modal-title").html(('@TempData["error"]'));
                $("#modal3").modal('show');
            });
            function closeModal() {
                modal.style.display = "none";
               
            }
            $("#btnHideModal").click(function () {
                $("#modal3").modal('hide');
            });
        </script>

    }
    }
</body>
```

**Note:** I have directly bind the `html('@TempData["error"]')` as `HTML` to your `modal-header class` and its working. Please have a try, It should work as expected.